# How can open source projects obtain license for commercial software without spending a lot of money?

Tags: .net, open-source, licensing

I just joined an open source project on codeplex. The project is based on the .NET compact framework. So the development tool is Visual Studio. Currently I am using some trial version of Visual Studio which is going to end and I wondered how can I obtain a valid license to work on the project without spending a lot of money. Please pay attention that the Express edition does not help me since my application is running on Windows Mobile 6.5 which is not supported on the Express edition (and the 2010 Express edition supports only Windows Mobile Phone 7 series development). In the general sense, are there some organizations that donate software licenses for open source projects?

Comment: Specifically for Microsoft products, if you happen to be self-employed, consider signing up for the [BizSpark](http://www.microsoft.com/bizspark/) or [WebsiteSpark](http://www.microsoft.com/web/websitespark/) programs. This will grant you licenses to Visual Studio and other software almost for free.

Comment: Interesting question.  Presumably the Mono toolset isn't compatible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Microsoft sometimes will give a complimentary MSDN subscription to open source developers that need more then the Express edition.  You can try asking via CodePlex: https://www.codeplex.com/site/contact

Comment: I have actually did request a subscription from Microsoft and it was approved. :)

Answer (score 1):

Are you a student? If so, you might take a look at https://www.dreamspark.com and see if that works for you.

Comment: 1. I am not a stuent
2. The dreamspark is not applicable for all unversities/colleges.
3. I am sure that the license for the dreamspark is for Academic usage and not for commercial usage of Visual Studio

Comment: ah but if it is for an open source project then it can be academic since you are learning.

Answer (score 1):

Try [Websitespark](http://www.microsoft.com/web/websitespark/). It's not completely free, you have to pay 100 USD after 3 years.

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is to start a sole proprietorship doing software. Then get the [Microsoft actionpack](https://partner.microsoft.com/40016455). Still costs money, but is cheaper.